# Sum of Absolute Differences Inequality

Tags: inequality

Given 2 sequences:
$\quad a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots \ge a_n$
$\quad b_1 \ge b_2 \ge \ldots \ge b_n$

$a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \cdots + a_nb_n \ge a_1b_{\pi(1)} + a_2b_{\pi(2)} + \cdots + a_nb_{\pi(n)}$

where $\pi(1), \pi(2), \ldots, \pi(n)$ is any permutation of $1, 2, \ldots, n$

is the Rearrangement Inequality.

Given 2 sequences:
$\quad a_1 \le a_2 \le \ldots \le a_n$
$\quad b_1 \le b_2 \le \ldots \le b_n$

Does anyone know if there is a name for the following inequality?

$\left| a_1 - b_1 \right| + \left| a_2 - b_2 \right| + \cdots + \left| a_n - b_n \right|  \le \left| a_1 - b_{\pi(1)} \right| + \left| a_2 - b_{\pi(2)} \right| + \cdots + \left| a_n - b_{\pi(n)} \right|$

Comment: Why did you cite the rearrangement inequality?

Comment: Just to provide some context to the question, although I probably did not have to.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. I wasn't looking for a proof. But it looks like in that question, no one was able to provide a formal name. So, I'll assume there isn't one.

Comment: @user137481 It doesn't appear to have an established name, indeed. That said, there are several references linked under the other question which I didn't follow all the way through.